# laravel email markdown template not showing images in mail body

Tags: laravel

> I want to send email with product images.So i am using laravel
> markdown mail template.But the probelm is when i send mail i only get
> the image link which is given bellow
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/vAO6oZDeIIFYwtz95dlz5ZyqghrOTsL0GNkDycJq.png

here is my markdown template code:

```
<head>
    <style>
       p{
        font-family:verdana;
        font-size: 10px;
         margin : 0;
        }
        .btn{
            text-align:center;
        } 

        

        .loginButton { padding: 7px 15px 8px 20px; }
    </style>
</head>

@component('mail::message')

<p>Dear {{ $data['supplier']->name}},</p><br>
<p>There is a new business opportunity:</p>
<p><b>Industry:</b> {{ $data['rfq']->category->industry }}</p>
<p><b>Product Category:</b> {{ $data['rfq']->category->name }}</p>
<p><b>Title:</b> {{ $data['rfq']->title }}</p>
<p><b>Quantity:</b> {{ $data['rfq']->quantity }}</p>
<p><b>Unit:</b> {{ $data['rfq']->unit }}</p>
<p><b>Unit price:</b> {{ $data['rfq']->unit_price }}</p>
<p><b>Payment method:</b> {{ $data['rfq']->payment_method }}</p>
<p><b>Delivery time:</b> {{ $data['rfq']->delivery_time }}</p><br>
<p>To reply, please login to your MerchantBay account and find the request in your RFQ menu.</p><br>
<p>You are receiving this notification because you produce Full Body in the requested country and the requested order quantity matches the information provided in your company profile. If you think this request does not fit to your business, please update your company profile.</p><br>




<p>Best regards,</p>
<p>your Merchant Bay team</p>
 @foreach($data['rfq']->images as $image) 
  {{ asset('storage/'.$image->image) }}<br>
 {{-- <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$image->image) }}" class="img-responsive"> --}}
@endforeach

@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the helpers paths instead.

If your images are being saved in the public folder use

```
public_path('folder_name/filename.png')
```

or if they are saved in the storage folder use

```
storage_path('folder_name/filename.png').
```

I assume you are using the public folder because you are using asset() so you should try

```
<img src="{{ public_path('storage/'.$image->image) }}" class="img-responsive">
```

Laravel Doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-storage-path

Comment: In which folder do you have the image stored?

Comment: public/storage  folder  my images are stored

Comment: The img portion of your code has been commented out 
{{-- <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$image->image) }}" class="img-responsive"> --}}
It should be 
{{ <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$image->image) }}" class="img-responsive"> }}

Comment: Remove the dashes after and before the curly brackets

Answer (score 1):

You have to embed the image to the email template  
This is an example, you can try like this

```
<img src="{{ embed(public_path() . '/logo.png') }}" alt="" class="top-logo" style="display: block; margin-left: auto;   margin-right: auto;">
```

Comment: Error
Call to undefined function embed()